# Syntax highlighting in patterns with built-in functions

Tags: bugs, syntax-highlighting

While working on my own `plotLegends` package I encoutered some weird behaviour of the front end's syntax highlighting. I reduced the problem to the following minimal example:

```
Unprotect[Plot];
AppendTo[Options[Plot], opt1 -> True];

Plot[a_, b_, c___, opt1 -> opt_, d___] :=
 foo[Plot[a, b, c, d], opt]

Plot[a_, b_, c___, opt1 -> opt_, d___] /; True :=
 foo[Plot[a, b, c, d], opt]
Protect[Plot];

Unprotect[ListPlot];
AppendTo[Options[ListPlot], opt1 -> True];

ListPlot[a_, c___, opt1 -> opt_, d___] :=
 foo[ListPlot[a, c, d], opt]

ListPlot[a_, c___, opt1 -> opt_, d___] /; True :=
 foo[ListPlot[a, c, d], opt]

Protect[ListPlot];
```

You can see what I mean by "weird behaviour" in the following screenshot:

[image]

For both `Plot` and `ListPlot`, adding `/;True` leads to the option being highlighted red (which it otherwise isn't) . But only for `Plot` the default green highlighting of the patterns gets lost too. Can anyone reproduce this? Is there any reason why `Plot` should differ from `ListPlot`?

I'm using version 8.0 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce this on OSX, but it is not specific to `Plot`. There are many other functions showing the same behavior. Try for instance

```
Integrate[a___] /; True := blub
```

When you delete the last *e* of `Integrate`, you see that the pattern `a___` is highlighted in green again.

All this happens in the front end where you cannot get much insight. A possible solution is to write the `Condition` explicitely:

```
Condition[Plot[a_, b_, c___, opt1 -> opt_, d___], True] := foo[Plot[a, b, c, d], opt]
```

This looks like you expected it here

[image: Mathematica graphics]